# port not opening even after adding rule in ufw?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, sinatra, port

I enabled port 4567 using **sudo ufw allow 4567**

when i do **sudo ufw status**

It lists as follows

[image]

When i check open port

https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

It says that port 4567 is closed. I am using Ubuntu 18. Am i missing anything else to open port 4567. I need to open this port for sinatra app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok the problem was with sinatra

turns out i need to run sinatra app in production mode

```
ruby myapp.rb -e production
```